# Sorting a 2D string array in Java in descending order and writing it to a file

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

So I have to read out a string from a file in Java. It's for a highscore system.
Each line of the file contains something similiar like this: "24/Kilian".
The number in front of the / is the score and the text after the / is the name.

Now, my problem is that I have to sort the scores descending and write them back into the file. The new scores should overwrite the old ones.

I tried it but I can't get it working properly.
I already wrote some code which reads the score + name line by line out of the file.

```
public static void sortScores() {
        String [][]scores = null;
        int i = 1;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("score.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                scores[i][0] = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("/"));
                scores[i][1] = line.substring(line.indexOf("/"), line.length());
                i++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So, this code basically writes the score and the name in a 2D array like this:

score[0][0] = "24";
score[0][1] = "Kilian";

score[1][0] = "33";
score[1][1] = "Name";

score[2][0] = "45";
score[2][1] = "AnotherName";

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: Are you aware that your code raises a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: instead of a 2d array you should use an 1d array of a custom class. This would make things lots easier.

Comment: If you don't have to use a 2D array for your homework, use a HashMap and sort the collection(descending) based on the keys (scores).  Always try to avoid substring/indexof searches, use a `split` and you'll have your key/value paris.

Comment: If you have the option, why not use a TreeMap?

Comment: "I can't get it working properly" anything more specific?

Comment: @jnbbender You're assuming that no two players have the same score?

Comment: So use a MultiMap

Comment: your index has to start with 0 right now it's 1

Comment: Just a stylistic comment: Your function is called sortScores(), but it reads scores from a file - presumably your intention was to also incorporate sorting into that function after the scores were read.   Don't do that.  Instead separate out the reading from the sorting and name your functions properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays.sort(arr, comparator) with a custom comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(theArray, new Comparator<String[]>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(final String[] first, final String[] second){
        // here you should usually check that first and second
        // a) are not null and b) have at least two items
        // updated after comments: comparing Double, not Strings
        // makes more sense, thanks Bart Kiers
        return Double.valueOf(second[1]).compareTo(
            Double.valueOf(first[1])
        );
    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(theArray));
```

Comment: This sorts the list ascending. Just negate the return value and it is fine. Well, I'd use Integer.parseInt() because Kilian only hat some integers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomend you to make a new `class Score` which holds your data (score + name) and add a new instance of `Score` into a `ArrayList` for each row you read from the file. After that you can implement a `Comparator` and sort your `ArrayList`. It's much easier because you don't know how big your string array will get and you need to know that when you're working with arrays.

```
public class Score {
    public Score(int score, String name) {
        this.score = score;
        this.name = name;
    }

    int score;
    String name;

    // getter
}


List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    scoreList.add(new Score(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("/"))), line.substring(line.indexOf("/"), line.length())));
}

Collections.sort(scoreList, new Comparator<Score>() {
    public int compare(Score s1, Score s2) {
        return s1.getScore() - s2.getScore();
    }
}

// write to file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Arrays`'s `sort`-Method:

```
Arrays.sort(scores, (a, b) -> -a[0].compareTo(b[0]));
```

But this lead to the case that "3" will be above "23". So probably you should create new class which holds the value and use an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
 HashMap<Integer, String > map = new HashMap<>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("score.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] lines = line.split("/");
            map.put(Integer.valueOf(lines[0]),lines[1]);
        }
        SortedSet<Integer> keys = new TreeSet<Integer>(map.keySet());
        keys.forEach(k -> System.out.println(map.get(k).toString() + " value " + k ));
```